# Is it possible to use pep8 and yapf in a Stash pre-receive hook?

Tags: java, git, githooks, pep8, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to write an Atlassian Stash pre-receive hook that will check if pushed code's python files comply with the python PEP-8 style convention. There are already two tools that do exactly what I want-- [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) and [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf).

However, I do not know how to integrate these tools to be used in a Stash pre-receive hook, which has to be written in Java. If I'm writing a Stash pre-receive hook in Java, how can I make use of pep8 and yapf?

Comment: I am essentially asking for advice on how to design my code. I know I have to write my code in Java, and it has to implement the [PreReceiveRepositoryHook](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/stash/3.9.1/spi/reference/com/atlassian/stash/hook/repository/PreReceiveRepositoryHook.html) interface. The method `onReceive` should return true if the pushed code's python files comply with PEP-8, and false if not. There is already a command-line tool called [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) to check if a python file complies with PEP-8. How can I use this command-line tool in Java?

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could try is use this [external hooks add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.ngs.stash.externalhooks.external-hooks) which can then run whatever scripts you need and return a result.

That said, I'd suggest considering also whether pre-receive is the right time to be making users wait, and possibly have to go back and fix their work. An alternative is a combination of pre-commit hooks on the client side (admittedly not always easy to enforce), and using an asynchronous process (using a build system such as Bamboo) to run checks. The former gives developers more immediate feedback, and the latter works as a safety net without being super-strict about it. In other words, you *might* be able to enforce this more through process (and the right cultural encouragement to do the right thing) than through strict tool enforcement. YMMV